# Append multiple tables on .htm files all contained in the same folder using Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have a .htm file that comes in daily with a random number of tables contained within.  Every morning, a new file is saved to the folder.  I sort and keep the most recent in Power Query for the purposes of this report but am wanting to have Power Query append every table in the file together.

I've posted a screenshot below showing how the file looks when it imports.  There may be 3 tables or 15 tables depending on the day.  I've not gotten very far, but this is what I have.

```
let
Source = Folder.Files("filepath"),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Date created", Order.Descending}}),
#"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",1),
#"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Kept First Rows", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
#"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
#"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Site", Int64.Type}, {"SName", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"DRAW", type number}, {"CUR", type text}, {"SAF", Int64.Type}, {"SCUR", type text}, {"Total", type number}})
```

in
#"Changed Type"

[image]

Comment: Im confused.  You want to combine all the tables that get produced from the code in a single query, or you want to combine all the tables that have been stored as separate queries?

Comment: I want to combine all of the Tables (not the "Document") in a single query.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe some one else will be able to help.

Comment: Please supply sample data that can be used to replicate your situation.

Comment: The solution was much simpler than I had originally thought.  I was able to figure out a workaround by Unpivoting the data column, expanding the data and deleting unnecessary columns.